# JQuery find returns undefined

Tags: jquery

can someone please explain why I get this behaviour?

In JQuery, if I run

```
var $('div#form-container').click( function() { 
   label = $(this).find('form label')[0];
   console.log(label);
});
```

I get

```
<label class=​"control radio">​ 
   " One "
   <input type=​"radio" name=​"profile" value=​"one">
   <span class=​"control-indicator">​</span>​
</label>​
```

but if I then try to get

```
var input = label.find('input');
```

it returns `undefined`.

How do I get it to return my `input` element? And why `find` cannot find `input`, since it's a descendant of `label`?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Exactly my question aswell. Is `var label = $(this).find('form label')[0];` inside a function?

Comment: `label.find('input');` will not work because `label` is a dom element reference

Comment: edited, sorry! $(this) is the clicked parent element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*why find cannot find input, since it's a descendant of label?*

Because `.find()` method is just for jQuery objects and you are trying to bind it on native dom node `$(this).find('form label')[0];` returns the DOM element not the jQuery object.

So when you apply `find()` method on it, will cause in error.

---

This is a dom node:

```
var label = $(this).find('form label')[0]; // it's a dom node
```

and you have to use jquery object:

```
var input = $(label).find('input');
```

---

if you want to get the first label in the form then you can use `.first(), :first, .eq(0), :eq(0) etc.` like:

```
var label = $(this).find('form label').first();
var input = label.find('input'); // returns the element now
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have label as dom element not jQuery element so can not use find with it.

```
var input = $(label).find('input');
```

Or

do not convert jQuery element to dom element in statement where you find label

```
var label = $(this).find('form label');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use dom element to access other dom elements,you need either id or class to get a particular element like this,

```
var input = $('.control radio').find('input');
```

Or

```
var input = $('label').find('input');
console.log(input);
```